# Is this site suitable for Color Theory?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago, I had a laptop from Dell. I installed Ubuntu and went to GNOME Color Manager. I set the ICC profile of the display to the default, but the default profile seemed to be broken. (The green point and the blue point were out.)
So at first, I went to ask for Dell, but I didn't see Dell's Q&A site. So then I went to Stack Exchange and thought this site was the most suitable. But then I noticed I had question ban on Stack Overflow, so I went for it first. (And I managed to lift it.)
Now that laptop is gone, but still, I have several question about Color Theory. Is this site suitable for Color Theory? If not, what site is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have better luck here with questions about signal processing aspects of image processing, and worse luck with vision and color science, especially if the question is not theoretical but about some software.

There's also https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/:

> Computer Graphics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for
>   computer graphics researchers and programmers.

and https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/, where software-specific questions appear to be well tolerated:

> Graphic Design Stack Exchange is a Question and Answer site for
>   Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts.

Comment: The second site seems suitable, thanks!